# Nuxtjs using typescript has problem with using meta

Tags: typescript, meta, nuxt.js

In Nuxtjs I put my permissionKeys of the page so that i could check user's access in the middleware. when my script'language is js everything works like a charm, however, in case of lagn="ts" I face errors.

I've looked for the solution and using vue-meta package, but i ended up getting the same error.

```
<script lang="ts">
export default {
  meta: {
    authorization: ['Organization/List']
  },
  data() {
    return {
           text: this.$t('organization.title'),
    }
   }
}
```

in this case i face this error: "Property '$t' does not exist on type '{ meta: { authorization: string[]; }; data(): any; }'."

I don't know what is the problem of using meta and global varaibles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the definition of meta key in route was added recently:
https://github.com/nuxt/typescript/pull/89

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the nuxt-property-decorator
this refer to the head property I'm not sure if this suits your need with plugin vue-meta but you can refer to the link given below about creating decorator to set vue-meta package

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator';

@Component({
  layout: 'home',
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'Test Title',
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'My custom description' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
export default class MainPage extends Vue {

}
</script>
```

or create your own decorator so that you can define it inside the class

@Meta

https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/issues/181#issuecomment-390258209

@Update 1/9/2019

You can use extendRoutes, this isn't advisable but still works :)

create permissions.js and inside it, it looks like this

```
export const normalUser = [
  'route-name-invoices',
  'route-name-invoices-create'
];
```

in your nuxt.config.js - import your permission js

```
import { normalUser } from './permissions'

...
// find the router or you can define it
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes) {
    return routes.map(route => {
      if (normalUser.includes(route.name)) {
        route.meta = { authorization: ['Organization/list'] };
      }
      return route;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it is possible to set meta without using decorator. By the way, with or without decorator, i cannot get meta properties in the middleware as follows:
`route.meta.forEach(item => {
        if (item.authorization && typeof item.authorization !== undefined) {
}
})`

Comment: okay I think you're referring to the router meta. in this case you can use the extendRoutes but this solution maybe long, but it's working enough for the this.$t you must inject it the vue instances [link](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#inject-into-vue-instances) or use a ts ignore [code]// @ts-ignore [/code] above the this.$t

Comment: Yes, I meant like this: (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html). However, in Nuxt, routes would generated based on folders convention. in Nuxt without ts this meta can be added in the component without any problem, but the issue would raise when I use ts :           
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
export default Vue.extend({})
I tried everything in the past days and ended up using beforeRouteEnter in the component. 
export default Vue.extend({
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {}
but in case of lacking access, it seems to enter the page for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

By using `<type="ts">` we are invoking TypeScript typechecking.
Now lets break the code down to see why the error is legitimate.

```
const obj = {
  meta: {
    authorization: ['Organization/List']
  },
  data() {
    return {
           text: this.$t('organization.title'),
    }
   }
};

export default obj;
```

Now, in the `data` method, `this` refers to the object `obj` and we reference the property `$t` of `this`, of `obj`. Clearly there is no such property.

Comment: I see what you are saying. But, I guess Vue works with ts a little bit more complicated. Because without "meta" it works. Moreover, $t is a function of i18n which is known all over the project because it is injected.

Comment: You are saying `{data() { return this.$t(''); }}` isn't a type check error?

Comment: No, it's not. please refer to the vuejs and typescript documents and you'll see this works. In fact, in my question, there is a problem with meta not this.$t